# find value from array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB called organization,

```
organization:{ 
{
   "_id": "520",
   "org_name": "group1",
   "type": "default",
   "zip_codes": {
     "0": {
       "0": "012345",
       "1": "044034"
    }
  }
},


{
   "_id": "521",
   "org_name": "hvbdf",
   "type": "custome",
   "zip_codes": {
     "0": {
       "0": "012345"
    }
  }
}   

}
```

I want to fetch total documents where type=default and zip_codes=012345

I trying this query,

```
$cursor = $collect->find(array('type' => 'default','zip_codes'=>array('012345')));
```

but it does not give output so please help me for this i am using php and mongodb.

Comment: Yourt document structure is not optimal for this type of querying, also it is wrong for this type of querying, you wish to make a single sert of zip codes in an array instead of making nested objects

Comment: This structure is so wrong! I agree with Sammaye

Comment: please suggest me structure for this collection. please help me.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the query for the same.

Comment: Structure could be: {name:'Default Organization',type:'default',zips:[000000,111111]}

Comment: hi how we insert this?  {name:'Default Organization',type:'default',zips:[000000,111111]}

Comment: I am afraid that you will need to read the documentation on that and do some research, however, as a pointer `$db->collection->insert(array('zips'=>array(000000,111111)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, there is a flaw in your schema for the `zip_codes` field. Compare what you have:

```
"zip_codes": {
    "0": {
        "0": "012345",
        "1": "044034"
    }
}
```

With the following:

```
"zip_codes": [
    "012345",
    "044034"
]
```

In the latter example, `zip_codes` is an array of strings. Your original example uses objects, and had an additional, redundant level of nesting. Unlike PHP, MongoDB's BSON format has no notion of associative arrays -- there are only arrays (numerically indexed starting with zero) and objects (a hash map or dictionary of key/value pairs).

Arrays will allow you the benefits of [multi-key indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-multi-key) (i.e. indexing all values in an array), as well as many [query and update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/), which take advantage of arrays. In particular, you can easily query for values in an array field using the syntax described in the [db.collection.find() documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-an-array-element). If you revise your schema, this last link should provide enough guidance for you to construct your query.